# Changing css styles with jQuery (within a container)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JFwDw/2/

What I'm wanting to do is use links to change the font-size and line-height of paragraphs only within a division id'd "content". I've made another division to make sure it isn't changing anywhere else... can't get it to work after a while of playing around with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `only within a division id'd "content"`
can you please explain that?

Comment: <div id="content"></div> That's all I mean.

Comment: You've left the JavaScript framework as MooTools...

Comment: A few suggestions: 1. id's should be unique - don't use them for more than one element 2. avoid inline click handlers - put them in your script 3. put your jquery code in a ready handler 4. when setting up a jsfiddle, set it up to use the jquery library if you want to use jquery

Comment: Oh, you have id="change" for each one of your tags. Removing or assigning different ids to each one solves the problem. If you want them to have similar properties, change id to class. Btwe, this may not solve your problem, but it is just good practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to change which selector you're using. Instead of doing to all `p` tags, you just want the ones under `#content`

```
$("#content p, #content ul").css()
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JFwDw/30/)

Your links also link to `<a href=""...` which causes the page to reload. I changed it to `href="#"` so this doesn't happen. You could also [prevent the default event](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) from happening inside the functions.

```
function origText() {
    event.preventDefault()
    ...
```

On a side note, I can't figure out why the functions are not working in the JS part of the fiddle...

Comment: the fiddle isn't using unique id's, nor is the fiddle set up to actually use jquery

Comment: What do you mean it isn't using unique IDs? `<div id="content">` is in there. And yeah, I changed it to jQuery.

Comment: `<a .. id="change">` is still in there a few times.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. As you can tell I'm still learning!

Comment: Am I missing something...? I have no idea what you guys are talking about. Can you explain please? I see the `a` tags have an id, but so what?

Comment: My comment was directed at the OP's markup, sachleen, not your answer, to suggest why the functions weren't working. The ID's actually wouldn't have mattered because the handlers were (unfortunately) inline, but jquery wasn't loaded in the fiddle, hence nothing was going to function.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one, your links are being activated and reloading the page.

Typically when you write jQuery, you would attached the events using selectors, not using inline code. This let's you keep your JavaScript and HTML in separate files as well as allows jQuery to remove events when needed.

```
<a href="#" id="bigText">big text</a>

$('#bigText').click( function(event) {
   // code here
} );
```

Then to prevent the default action (following the link), you can use the jQuery method, prevent default action.

```
$('#bigText').click( function(event) {
   event.preventDefaultAction();
   // code here
} );
```

You may also what to wrap you event binding code withing a document ready event in order to make sure that the DOM is loaded before trying to attach events to it.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('#bigText').click( function(event) {
      event.preventDefaultAction();
      // code here
   } );
} );
```

Also, you would typically want to add a class to change an element's styles rather than using jQuery to change the style. It's more performant. Also, if you want to only affect element within a container, you can use the jQuery "find" method to do so.

```
$('#someContainer').find('p').addClass('someClass');
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/JFwDw/34/

This is working for me.

**Edit:** I think that this is what you're trying to achieve!